# Capturing cookies in JMeter

Tags: ajax, cookies, jmeter

I am facing issue for AJAX call in jmeter.

**A new Ajax Token generated every time by taking value of cookies**

```
efpcookieiQmdOSdtYvVcktctGnNfrwCC4350121699716256984xxxxxxxxx=nAgvF4MhWoTTb7NTV8zaowCC;
```

I need to pass the cookie in the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/?usecase=maintain_account&command=load_acc_type_command&guid=${uid6}&commandorigin=0.create_account_step1_view&fpid=efpcookieiQmdOSdtYvVcktctGnNfrwCC4350121699716256984xxxxxxxxx&view=create_account_step1_view&pipe=ajax&hash=hash1287912XXXX&ajaxtoken=${ajaxtokan}&accProdId=1`

How can I capture this?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://javaworks.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/setting-cookie-in-jmeter/).

Comment: You need to include Regular Expression Extractor (Post processor) and select the filed to check as `Response Headers` and extract the cookie info and pass that in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the jmeter.properties file inside the JMeter bin directory, and set **CookieManager.save.cookies=true**

Restart JMeter and add a HTTP Cookie Manager. Now, just replace the Cookie value with ${COOKIE_fpid}, this is:

usecase=maintain_account&command=load_acc_type_command&guid=${uid6}&commandorigin=0.create_account_step1_view&fpid=${COOKIE_fpid}&view=create_account_step1_view&pipe=ajax&hash=hash1287912XXXX&ajaxtoken=${ajaxtokan}&accProdId=1